# Reading words/phrases into columns with spaces

Tags: bash

I'm trying to read in from a text file that's formatted in a fashion such as (where you have a key word column and an associated key value):

tangerine 12

durian fruit 5

apple 3.5

Using the read function I can read them in as columns, but only if the columns are each essentially one word. In an example case such as above, I'm unsure of what to do because the second entry is two words, but I'd like to store it as one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a regex:

```
while read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ ^(.*)\ (.*)$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}|${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done < file
```

Output:

```
tangerine|12
durian fruit|5
apple|3.5
```

`${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` contains first column and `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` second column.

Comment: Works great, thanks! Would you be able to give a quick overview of how the regex formatting you have works? I know a bit of regex overall, but it looks like a bit of mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: Followup question: Is it possible to iterate through each of the entries in either BASH_REMATCH 1 or 2 using a loop? I attempted to use a for loop with a phrase such as: "for i in "${BASH_REMATCH[1]"", but it only gets the last entry in the list.

Comment: My language skills are not enough. The `\` is only used to escape the whitespace character. The regular expression is processed from left to right. `*` is greedy and trying to capture as much as possible. To your second question: I would omit the double quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use something other than a space to separate the name from the count, like a tab. Then you could use

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r fruit count; do
    echo "Fruit: $fruit"
    echo "Count: $count"
done < data.txt
```

If you can't make that change, you can read each line into an array and rejoin the first set of columns. This will lose any specific white space, though.

```
while read -a data; do
    fruit=${data[*]:0:${#data[@]}-1}
    count=${data[@]:${#data[@]}-1}
done < data.txt
```

Either way, you can build up arrays of fruit names and counts inside the loop.

```
while ...; do
    fruits+=("$fruit")
    counts+=("$count")
done << ...

for ((i=0; i<${#fruits[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "Fruit #$i: there are ${counts[i]} ${fruits[i]}(s)"
done
```

Comment: With Bash 4.3 or newer, you can access the last element with `${data[-1]}`.

Comment: I always forget when and what allows you to use negative indices.

Comment: This also works great, thanks! I figured with the note that any specific white space would be lost that for example, "durian fruit" would turn into "durianfruit", but it works fine and seems to keep the space. I do have the same question as the first answer; can I iterate over the contents of fruit and count as arrays?

Comment: I should have been more specific. If you had multiple spaces between "durian" and "fruit", the array solution would collapse it to a single space. You can *create* arrays of fruits and counts; I'll add that.